# Assigning column name to Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

What I have set out below is my unsuccessful attempt at creating a pandas series and then converting it to a dataframe and using the series name as the column name:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas import DataFrame

start = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1).replace(microsecond=0)
stop = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 31).replace(microsecond=0)


all_dates = pd.date_range(start=start, end=stop)

df = pd.Series(all_dates, name = 'dates')
df = pd.DataFrame(all_dates)

print(df)
```

What I get is column name '0' instead of 'dates'

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the df.dataseries and add the in the DataFrame the columns as a list. In this case it was only one

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas import DataFrame

start = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1).replace(microsecond=0)
stop = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 31).replace(microsecond=0)


all_dates = pd.date_range(start=start, end=stop)


df = pd.DataFrame(all_dates, columns=['dates'])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have now spotted the obvious issue.

Shame on me!!

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas import DataFrame

start = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1).replace(microsecond=0)
stop = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 31).replace(microsecond=0)


all_dates = pd.date_range(start=start, end=stop)

all_dates = pd.Series(all_dates, name = 'dates')
df = pd.DataFrame(all_dates)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a name to your column:

```
df.columns = ['date']
```